# Spring boot security is not loading Angular 7 app build files

Tags: angular, spring, spring-boot, gradle, war

I am trying to build war file by including angular build files. I have placed Angular 7 build files inside 
`src/main/resources/static` folder. I am using Gradle as build tool.

Security class looks as mentioned below.

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)
@EnableGlobalAuthentication
public class JWTWebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    private JwtUnAuthorizedResponseAuthenticationEntryPoint jwtUnAuthorizedResponseAuthenticationEntryPoint;

    @Autowired
    private UserDetailsService jwtInMemoryUserDetailsService;

    @Autowired
    private JwtTokenAuthorizationOncePerRequestFilter jwtAuthenticationTokenFilter;

    @Value("${jwt.get.token.uri}")
    private String authenticationPath;

    @Autowired
    public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth
            .userDetailsService(jwtInMemoryUserDetailsService)
            .passwordEncoder(passwordEncoderBean());
    }

    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoderBean() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }

    @Bean
    @Override
    public AuthenticationManager authenticationManagerBean() throws Exception {
        return super.authenticationManagerBean();
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity httpSecurity) throws Exception {
        httpSecurity
            .csrf().disable()
            .exceptionHandling().authenticationEntryPoint(jwtUnAuthorizedResponseAuthenticationEntryPoint).and()
            //.sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS).and()
            .authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers(HttpMethod.OPTIONS,"/fbts/api**").permitAll()
            .anyRequest().authenticated().and()
            .httpBasic()
            .and().formLogin().disable();

       httpSecurity
            .addFilterBefore(jwtAuthenticationTokenFilter, UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);

        httpSecurity
            .headers()
            .frameOptions().sameOrigin()  //H2 Console Needs this setting
            .cacheControl(); //disable caching
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(WebSecurity webSecurity) throws Exception {
        webSecurity
            .ignoring()
            .antMatchers(
                HttpMethod.POST,
                authenticationPath
            )
            .antMatchers(HttpMethod.OPTIONS, "/**")
            .and()
            .ignoring()
            .antMatchers(
                HttpMethod.GET,
                "/" //Other Stuff You want to Ignore
            )
            .and()
            .ignoring()
            .antMatchers("/h2-console/**/**");
    }
}
```

I am getting below issue while trying to access the app
[image]

Do I want to add anything to ignore .js files. I also tried ignoring .js files, but when I ignored .js files my Rest API's are not secured. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

In your last code line `.antMatchers("/h2-console/**/**");` you have to add all resources that should be excluded from authorization.
For instance

`.antMatchers("/h2-console/**/**"."/resources/**", "/static/**", "/assets/**", "/index.html", "/**/*.css", "/**/*.js", "/**/*.png", "/**/*.jpg", "/**/*.gif", "/**/*.svg", "/**/favicon.ico");`

Comment: Thanks for your response. I tried same, after that app is loading, but Rest API's are not secured after building .war file.

Comment: When I am running the app in embedded tomcat Rest API's are secured. But when I deployed war file to external tomcat Rest API's are not secured.